# Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/products/download/image001.png

Tags: angular, spring-boot, download, jsonparser

Hello guys im building an application with spring boot and angular, im uploading files in the server and when trying to download this files am getting this error "error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse".
Here is part of my code that is concerned

**My Component**

```html
downloadProduct(fileUrl){
    this.httpClientService.downProduct(fileUrl).subscribe(response => {
      window.open(response.url, '_blank');
    }
    )
  }
```

**My Service**

```html
public downProduct(fileUrl: string | undefined): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get(this.urlBack+"products/download/"+fileUrl, {
      responseType: 'json'
    });
  }
```

**And My Spring Controller**

```js
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @GetMapping("download/{filename}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFiles(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("weeeeeesh");
        Path filePath = get(DIRECTORY).toAbsolutePath().normalize().resolve(filename);
        if(!Files.exists(filePath)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(filename + " was not found on the server");
        }
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("File-Name", filename);
        httpHeaders.add(CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;File-Name=" + resource.getFilename());
        System.out.println(resource.getFilename());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(Files.probeContentType(filePath)))
                .headers(httpHeaders).body(resource);

    }
```

and here is the **error shown in the console**

```html
SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:123146:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9799:31) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:83895:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9798:60) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9571:47) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9880:34) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10993:14) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:11030:21)
message: "Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:123146:51)\n    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http:/
```

so please how can i fix this problem

Comment: Please don't post images of code http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Http.get expects a json response. If you want to show the image, simply use an <img> tag in your template with the correct source in there..

Comment: @MikeOne i want to download it from the server not show it

Comment: @MarkB that the first question im posting sorry, i will change